# Can we exclude or include only particular file extensions from Databricks Autoloader?

Tags: databricks, databricks-autoloader

Right now the databricks autoloader requires a directory path where all the files will be loaded from. But in case some other kind of log files also start coming in in that directory - is there a way to ask Autoloader to exclude those files while preparing dataframe?

```
df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \
  .option(<cloudFiles-option>, <option-value>) \
  .schema(<schema>) \
  .load(<input-path>)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Autoloader supports specification of the glob string as `<input-path>` - from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/structured-streaming/auto-loader-gen2#use-cloudfiles-source):

> `<input-path>` can contain file glob patterns

Glob syntax support [different options](https://hail.is/docs/0.2/hadoop_glob_patterns.html), like, `*` for any character, etc.  So you can specify `input-path` as, `path/*.json` for example.  You can exclude files as well, but building that pattern could be slightly more complicated, compared to inclusion pattern, but it's still possible - for example, `*.[^l][^o][^g]` should exclude files with `.log` extension

Comment: Alex this was really helpful. I though this wont work with sub nested dynamic generated folders but it worked for that as well. This solved the issue for me!

Answer (score -1):

Use `pathGlobFilter` as one of the option and provide a regex to filter a file type or file with specific name.

For instance, to skip files with filename as A1.csv, A2.csv .... A9.csv from load location, the value for `pathGlobFilter` will look like:

```
df = spark.read.load("/file/load/location,
                     format="csv", 
                     schema=schema, 
                     pathGlobFilter="A[0-9].csv")
```

Comment: Fromd docs: "`pathGlobFilter` is used to only **include** files with file names matching the pattern", so this won't skip these files